# Contactless measurement of very low current (fraction of mA)

Tags: current, sensor, atmega, inductive

I'm trying to measure the current from Vtarget of stk600 evaluation board. I'm thinking of designing an inductive sensing circuit, which could give me a precise current measurement. For now, I'm using the conventional method of shunt resistance. Could you please suggest me any ideas to get the current measurement contactless ?

(Very low Current in the range of  fractions of mA, contactless)
P.s-I tried measuring with a couple of current probes but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide more information? This is unclear. What are you trying to measure? It might be good to draw a block diagram or schematic. Please see: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Also, your question appears to be based on opinion. Please modify your question so it is more specific and can be answered with a singular answer, like "How can I measure uA's of current from my [fill in the part number] inductive sensor?" A good post will stand on its own with no further questions that need to be asked to give an answer.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Hall sensors you could look at fluxgate sensors.  TI has integrated flux gate ICs for open and closed-loop current sensing.  One example is here:

[Flux Gate Sensor](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv421.pdf)

Flux gate sensors have much higher sensitivity and potentially higher accuracy than Hall effect sensors, and the integrated sensor versions make them fairly easy to use.  They don't need de-gaussing like Hall sensors since the sensing element is driven to saturation in both directions continually.

Comment: Hmm, downvotes all around.  The OP asked for methods of doing contactless current sensing.  Both Hall and Fluxgate sensors are legitimate options so I don't understand the down votes?  A CT might be an option if it were pure AC, but we don't know that.

Answer (score 1):

A hall sensor will measure current without contact.  Allegro Micro makes lots of them, either PCB mount or clip on to wire types.